# Angular build index.html not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm-live-server

I have taken the build of angular project and got dist folder.when i am trying to open the index.html in browser.I am getting the following error like failed to load resources and file not found for inline.bundle.js ,polyfil.bundle.js and many files.
[image]
Though this files added in the script tag and i didnt change the path of this file still not working.But if i run this from live server it is working.
[image]
Explain why it is not working without server?
Why it is not loading the inline.bundle.js,polyfill.bundle.js which are js file?

Comment: You have to open the page using `localhost:4200`, it is said when you run `ng start`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your files are not found because base URL changed.

You can workaround this one by using `<base href="./">` in your `index.html`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: It is working Thanks.Why it is still working if i remove the base element?

Comment: Yes it is woking if the element not there

Comment: I'm not sure Sir, I don't know what is the default base url once you remove this tag

Comment: This didn't work for me. I got nothing when I add ```<base href="./">```. When I removed base tag, I got an error.
```Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `ng build --base-href ./` command, so that modifying the HTML  file is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla:

```
The HTML <base> element specifies the base URL to use for 
all relative URLs in a document. There can be only one <base> element in a document.
```

This means all the compiled resources are being referenced in relation to the root of the system. for instance the style and the images are in the same folder as the index.html. making the base url `<base href="/">` or `<base href="foldername of the index.html">`makes it to reference to the current folder.