# Why angular app dist build needs to be served on web server?

Tags: angular, webserver

why we need a web server for the angular build?

1. Why I cannot directly run dist/index.html?
2. If my angular build has all the bundled js files hosted and someone copies page source then why it does not run?

I referenced: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148872/angular-build-index-html-not-working) and [Github discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13948#issuecomment-302727428) to understand this process. 
But could not find out the reason behind why the angular app cannot be accessed through file://.

It would be great if someone can spare some time to explain this conceptual issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you change <base href=""/> in index.html?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Any idea?

Comment: @sebastianromero Sorry I did not find reason behind this. For now running on web server.